# Visual Studio 2010 renaming project and main forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I guess a lot of people start working on something. And then later they find-out the names don't really cover the end product. Or well at least, I do choose often poor names for stuff, I start programming faster then thinking about things like that (in the end I often rename my buttons too so my code becomes more clear too).

What is the best way of a current work in progress (not finished) to rename it? Without breaking the code, or do a lot after editing.

The reason I ask it here is I've seen it gone wrong a few times, leaving me code that didn't work any more so I better as how to do this and where in which pane, it's best to rename.

So what's wrong? Well in the upper right pane of Visual Studio 2010 C# (solution explorer):

- The solution itself has a wrong name
- The next line of it has the wrong name
- And the main form could be improved too

Answer (score 0):

Well usually you should change the file name of your class in the solution explorer and it should ask if you want to change all references, though sometimes it can go wrong so to double check you can replace all command to find all references of old name and replace with the new one..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx

Also if you change in code, the name of a class or variable or anything and then you should see small line under the changed name, stand with the mouse pointer on the variable and press ctrl+. (ctrl dot) And that shoul pop up small options and the first one should let you change all references of that variable new name also:

http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you were to rename the main form it would ask you if you want to change all references to it, you say yes and that problem is solved.

Renaming the solution is equally simple, just right click in the Solution Explorer and rename. It won't break your local build or anything.

I don't know what "The next line of it has the wrong name" is referring to (the project maybe?) but the same probably goes for it.